# ng-non-bindable with ng-if in Angular Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angular-google-maps

So I read [Why is ng-non-bindable required for <ui-gmap-windows> element in Angular Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757926/why-is-ng-non-bindable-required-for-ui-gmap-windows-element-in-angular-google) 
and I get how ng-non-bindable is used in the directive.

My problem is that I'm trying to use ng-if to conditionally reveal some icons in my marker infowindows.  ng-if doesn't work with ng-non-bindable, and of course, the info windows don't work without it.

If someone can tell me how to make ng-if work in this situation or give an alternative solution, i'd greatly appreciate it.

```
      <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>{{obj.name}}<br>{{distance}} miles
            <span class="ion-man" ng-if="obj.men"></span>
          <span class="ion-woman" ng-if="obj.women"></span>
            <span class="ion-ios-people" ng-if="obj.people"></span>  
            </div>                     
          </div>
      </ui-gmap-windows>
```

Comment: You could just wrap that in another div with ng-if ? Or wrap the content of div in a span with ng-non-bindable?

Comment: I need each one to be conditional

Comment: Ok. What i meant is `<div ng-if="someCond"><span ng-non-bindable>{{obj.name}}<br>{{distance}} miles</span></div>`

Comment: yeah, that could work ---i'd have to do it a few times over to satisfy each condition, which feels slightly awkward, but whatever works...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the templateUrl and templateParameter attributes on the ui-gmap-windows directive. The templateUrl is a property on the object that you're passing in which is a string that is the path to the .html template you want to use. The templateParameter is a property on the object that you are passing which is an object containing the parameters you want passed in. See code below. Also you can reference the docs here: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/windows

```
<ui-gmap-windows  idKey="'name'" show="show" templateUrl="'pathToHtmltemplate.html'" templateParameter="'{name: 'name', distance: 1.3, womens_restroom: true}'">
</ui-gmap-windows>
```

Then in your html template you can use ng-if no problem.

Note you have to reference the object you pass into templateParameter as parameter in the html template so the

pathToHtmlTemplate.html file would look like this

```
<div>
    {{parameter.name}}<br>{{parameter.distance}} miles
    <span ng-if="parameter.womens_restroom" class="ion-woman"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is because, `ng-if` (`600`) has lower priority than `ng-non-bindable` (`1000`) and `ng-non-bindable` is `terminal:true` so `ng-if` ***never compiles*** due to the terminal nature of `ng-non-bindable`. You could try using `ng-switch` (`1200`) directly on the element with `ng-non-bindable` though since it has ***higher priority*** but not sure if that is applicable in your case if you may have multiple conditions that can be true.

You can as well create your own directive say my-non-bindable anddefine it with configuration, `{priority:599, terminal:true}` and use it with `ng-if` say:

```
.directive('gmapTemplate', function() {
  return {
    priority: 599,
    terminal: true
  };
});
```

and use it with `ng-if`.

```
<div gmap-template ng-if="someCond">{{obj.name}}<br>{{distance}} miles
```

Otherwise you will have to wrap non bindables within element with `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="someCond">
   <span ng-non-bindable>{{obj.name}}<br>{{distance}} miles</span>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('gmapNonBindable', function() {
  return {
    priority: 599,
    terminal: true
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="test:123; show:false">
  Show-->
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="show" />
  <div gmap-Non-Bindable ng-if="show">{{test}}</div>


</div>
```